# Добавление фотографии в кукисы

Tags: jquery, html

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста доделать добавление фотографий в кукисы. Идея такая: есть набор товаров, человек заходит на сайт, и при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить в закладки", товары, которые ему понравились сохраняются в куки, и при следующем входе на сайт, он имеет возможность просмотреть их. Вот, что у меня пока есть:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(.save_button).click{
        if(navigator.cookieEnabled){
            $savedLi = this.siblings(); 
            if ($.cookie('dress') == $savedLi){
                exit;
            }
            else{
                $.cookie('dress', $savedLi, {
                    expires: 20,
                    path: '/';
                });
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('Чтобы добавить платье в закладки, у Вас должно быть включено сохранение в кукис');
        }
    }

})
```

Я использовал плагин jquery.cookie.js.
А вот HTML-разметка:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
    <ul id="ss" class="ss">                 
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-largesrc="1.jpg" data-title="1146" data-description="">
            <img src="1A.jpg"/>
        <p class="article">1146</p>
        </a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#" data-largesrc="2.jpg" data-title="2146" data-description="">
            <img src="2A.jpg"/>
        <p class="article">2146</p>
        </a>
    </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, весь < li > (в котором находится эта кнопка) со всем содержимым загонялся в переменную.
Разметку поменять не могу, так как использую 1 библиотеку для вывода галереи.
p.s.: Фотографий в общей сумме 170-200 штук.

Comment: А может всё-таки поискать более простое решение, не требующее паразитного трафика нехилого размера (сколько одна фотография весит?)

Comment: а почему не сохранять только id на картинку? А картинки в кукисы не сохранишь - размер то ограничен.

Comment: @KoVadim, ТС имел в виду сохранить код, а не изображение, но всё равно согласен, что 4Кб, не располагают к хранению такого рода информации. Если уж и сохранять код, то LocalStorage больше подойдет. А так - да, достаточно ID-шника

Comment: но там 170 фотографий + будет еще около двух сотен, я же не буду прописывать 400 айдишников

Comment: и да, я имел ввиду сохранять лишь кусочек кода, а именно от < li > до < /li >

Comment: Тогда в куках хранить id пользователя, а список хранить на сервере. Ну и примитивную регистрацию прикрутить. Тогда можно будет получить доступ к своим картинкам и на другом компе.

Но если очень сильно хочется хранить локально, тогда Вы выбрали неверную технологию. Вам декстопное приложение писать нужно.